# Moving text files one Dir to Another Dir

Tags: c#, file, directory

```
string sourcePath= @"F:\test\";
string targetPath= @"F:\transferedFiles\";

string filename="example.txt";

string sourceFile= System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath,filename);

string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, filename);
System.IO.File.Move(sourceFile , destFile );
```

This Program is working on my local machine but on the server it's not working.

Comment: You haven't asked the question.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: I'm testing many times. In my local machine it's working fine, but when published on server then file moving not work.

Comment: What is the exception on the remote machine?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: In the exception  "Access to the path is denied."

Comment: I have update network file permission and it's working now. Thank you for your valuable response.